# Can't use Processing 3 in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, processing

Well the thing is simple i guess.
I'm kinda of new in Java and IntelliJ but i wanted to use Processing in IntelliJ because of the auto - complete.
Well i've added the core.jar library from processing.
[image]

I've wrote the code (i tried with only what it is inside main and still won't work so i guess there is no problem with the overridden functions).

```java
package com.company;

import processing.core.PApplet;

class MainClass extends PApplet {

    @Override
    public void setup() {
        super.setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        super.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void settings() {
        super.settings();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PApplet.main("Test");
    }
}
```

(edit: i tried with MainClass and com.company.MainClass and didn't work either)
And when i tried to run it this pops out.

```java
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test
    at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10697)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10504)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10486)
    at com.company.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10690)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is telling you that it can't find a class named `Test`. You're using a `String` value of `"Test"`. Do you have a class named `Test`?

Your main class is called `MainTest`. But you're passing in a `String` value of `"Test"` to the `PApplet.main()` function. Where are you getting the `"Test"` value?

It should be:

```
PApplet.main("MainClass");
```

Or possibly:

```
PApplet.main("com.company.MainClass");
```

By the way, if autocomplete is the main reason you're switching to an IDE, I'd actually recommend sticking with the Processing editor. Using an IDE too soon will hide a lot of the stuff you need to learn from you.

And in the future, please don't post screenshots of code or error messages. Copy and paste them as text instead.

Comment: first sorry for the copy and paste i will edit it
second when i try to pass it "MainClass" it says the same thing and when i pass "com.company.MainClass" it says:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class processing.core.PApplet can not access a member of class com.company.MainClass with modifiers ""
I will probably go on the default ide for the moment as you said, thank anyway

Comment: @Willneeh That's a different error, which means your first error has been solved. Now you need to fix your second error. Your second error is caused because your main class should be `public`.

Comment: it is  
public static void main(String args[]) {
        PApplet.main("com.company.MainClass");
    }

Comment: @Willneeh That's the function. Your error is talking about the class itself.

Comment: Awww, well that was a dumb mistake from my side:)), problem solved, thank you